# ASP.NET 5 with Entity Framework 7 - No database providers are configured when try to seed DB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-applications

I am playing with ASP.NET 5 project using EF7. I have created basic testing model, made code-first migrations, database updates and now I try to send some data to created database.

I am using the default DbContext (ApplicationDbContext.cs) included with project tepmplates. When I have tried to send data with controller, everything worked. Now I want to seed database on start. To do this, I have created seed extension method to **ApplicationDbContext**:

```
public static class ProjectExtensions
{

    public static void SeedDB(this ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        context.Add(new TestingModel() { Name = "foo" });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

Then, I have added method calling inside **Startup.cs** in **Configure** method:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();

            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                context.SeedDB();
            }

        }
```

But when I try to run the project, system throws an **exception**:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No database providers are configured. Configure a database provider by overriding OnConfiguring in your DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up services.
```

It seem strange, becuase database provider should be already configured. As I said, I am using default context with default settings. And when I call controller to make some CRUD operation, everything is working.

Does anyone know, where is a mistake?

Comment: I have not used EF7, and only know a *little* about it. But you didn't show the code that the error method mentions. And your configuration doesn't show registering any providers. I know EF7 supports many providers, and I'm assuming that you need to tell it which provider to use by following the directions in the error. Always try what the error tells you to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. All seems to be fixed with this edit inside the **Startup.cs** in **Configure** method:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();

            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                           .CreateScope())
            {
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>().SeedDB();
            }

        }
```

Hope this could help someone with the same problem :)